# Http post request not working

Tags: java, http, jsoup

I want to search the following in Google query box:

```
http://www.cmu.edu/silicon-valley/ faculty directory
```

Unfortunately, the following code does not work:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=http%3A%%2F%%2F%www.cmu.edu%2F%silicon-valley%2F%20faculty20directory").get();
```

nor does this one:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=http%3A%%2F%%2F%www.cmu.edu%2F%silicon-valley%2F%20faculty20or20directory").get();
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit**: *not working* means Google didn't return any result as we see from browser.

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=http%3A%"%2F%%2F%www.cmu.edu%2F%silicon-valley%2F%20faculty").get();
```

The code above works though. It's equivalent to Googling "`http://www.cmu.edu/silicon-valley/ faculty`".

**Edit**: I have the following trick in my program, so bot-rule is not an issue:

```
.userAgent("Mozilla")
```

Comment: Also, define "does not work"

Comment: Well, is it just me or your query string has a very strange kind of encoding? What does `%"` stand for, or `%%2F`, or those `20`s without a `%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmu.edu%2Fsilicon-valley%2F+faculty+directory")` leads to a 403 error (Forbidden) as google forbis robots to access its results

You'll have to change the User Agent String if you want to do that

`doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmu.edu%2Fsilicon-valley%2F+faculty+directory").header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17").get()` should work as expected, but could be against Google's Terms of Use.

Comment: See my update. It's not the problem. Even with `agent()`, it does not work.

Comment: My request has been tested before being post... `Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmu.edu%2Fsilicon-valley%2F+faculty+directory").header("User-Agent", "Mozilla").get()` works for me, either

Comment: Have you tried to use my request directly ? What doesn't work ? I can't understand why your code even compile, as it has double quotes in the middle.

Comment: The double quotes were just typos. Sorry for the confusion. It works when I replace the `20`(single space) by the plus sign you suggested. I still wonder why.